# change multiview index with enum in jquery

Tags: jquery, enums, multiview

I want to change mutiview's active index using enum. How can I create enum for this?

My code is:

```
protected void BtnMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
```

I want to write `'Menu'` instead of `'0'` using enum, how to do that ?

Thanks for future advise

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need Jquery for this.

Declare your enum

```
  enum Menu {
         Menu1,
         Menu2

     };
```

And in your event handler

```
protected void BtnMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string activeIndex=Enum.Format(typeof(Menu),Menu.Menu2,"d"); //d is a constant to output value in digit format
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = Convert.ToInt32(activeIndex);
}
```

This will set the active view to  1.The index is zero based.This [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum) will help you to understand enums better .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. Multi view is a server side control and does not render inactive views to the client at all.

Consider using a client side multiview.

I.e. [jquery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs) or simply a set of divs (asp Panels) with style='display:none' that you can display/hide using something like `$('#viewMenu').fadeIn() / .fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

On the server side (not jQuery) you can use `MultiView1.SetActiveView(viewMenu)` where `viewMenu` is the ID of one of the views inside the multiview.

In this way Intellisense will help you and you don't have to mantain an enum when you add / remove views.